# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a secondary partition of a tertiary HDD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, boot-partition

I'm currently running a Windows 10 boot drive (120GB SSD) alongside two other HDDs, a 1TB & 3TB that I use for programs and files respectively.

I have shrunk the partition on my 3rd (3TB) drive to make room for a Ubuntu GNOME install, but I am not having success while installing it. Each time I attempt to install, the grub boot loader fails to install. (I get an error something along the lines of "grub was unable to install to /target/")

I would like to retain a file storage partition on my third drive but also use it as a bootable drive for Ubuntu. I envision using F12 when my computer starts up and selecting my SSD for a normal Windows boot, or selecting my 3TB HDD to get into Ubuntu (going through grub). Is this even possible, and if so how can I accomplish it?

Comment: are you booting EFI or Legacy?

Answer (score 0):

After much more research and playing around I figured out that one of they key things that I needed to do to accomplish this was to create a ~200 MB partition for EFI on the drive that I installed Ubuntu to. I also moved my storage partition to the right so that the EFI partition and partition for / were at the beginning of my hard drive space, although I do know if this was necessary.

Comment: since this worked for you, you can mark it as accepted